# How can I cut an image using a color pattern?

Tags: java, image, colors, java-2d, shapes

I am developing a small program which cuts images by the color.

That's will be easiest to explain using this example image:

[image: black with a purple splotch of color]

And I want to create a new image just with the purple form, without the black frame.

Does anyone have any ideas? I am using Java 2D so I think that I need to create an Object "Shape" with the purple area of the first image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the image is literally like the one you show, you could:

- load the image into a BufferedImage (with ImageIO.read())
- create a new BufferedImage of the same size, ensuring it has an alpha layer (e.g. set its type to BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR)
- "manually" go through each pixel in turn in the loaded BufferedImage, getting the pixel colour with getRGB() and checking if it's black
- if the colour is black, set the corresponding pixel to transparent in the new image, else to the original colour from the first image (see setRGB() method)
- save the new image (with ImageIO.write())

There are fancier ways, but this simple method is nice and understandable and will work fine for images of the type you showed.

Comment: Great answer! At the end I found the solution! And all thanks to you!
Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use some flood-fill algorithm that finds the boundries of the purple area:

Wikipedia has a page on it with excellent pseudo code and animations.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! Neil Coffey gave me the best solution, but thanks anyway!